# A-frame text is not displaying in Android phone

Tags: android, aframe

I am creating a virtual tour and I also added a hot spot that when gazed or click a text should display. My problem is the text is not displaying, I am running my website in my android phone. Can you please check my code?

My other problem is one of my equirectangular photo won't display, that is the image with an id of "showroompano". Here is my glitch. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/16dc3064-6cd6-499c-993b-1495757a3aac

```js
         var showText = document.querySelector('#hotspotText');
        var textPopover = document.querySelector('#textPopover');
        var gotoAnotherScene = document.querySelector("#sceneHotspot1");
        var scene = document.querySelector("#pano");
        
      
        showText.addEventListener('click', function()
        {

          console.log("show text");
          textPopover.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
          cursor.setAttribute('visible', 'false');

        });
      
        gotoAnotherScene.addEventListener('click', function()
        {
          
          var currScene = scene.getAttribute('src');
          
          if (currScene == "#reception")
            {
              
              console.log("the arrow has clicked");
              scene.setAttribute('src', '#salesroompano');
              gotoAnotherScene.setAttribute('position', '-6 -2 -4');
              gotoAnotherScene.setAttribute('rotation', '-90 45 0');
              showText.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
              
            }
          else if (currScene == "#salesroompano")
            {
                   
              console.log("the arrow has clicked");
              scene.setAttribute('src', '#reception');
              gotoAnotherScene.setAttribute('position', '2 1 4');
              gotoAnotherScene.setAttribute('rotation', '90 30 0');
              showText.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
              
            }
          
        });
      
       function closeText()
        {               
          textPopover.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
          cursor.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>showroom vr</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/84/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onmousedown="closeText()">
    <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: true">
      <assets>
        <img id="reception" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/5874228b-d8b5-4335-9d1b-5e623a35b987%2Freception.jpg?1498790772677">
        <img id="showroompano" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/5874228b-d8b5-4335-9d1b-5e623a35b987%2Fshowroom.png?1498795620954">
        <img id="salesroompano" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/5874228b-d8b5-4335-9d1b-5e623a35b987%2Fsales.jpg?1498790765222"> 
        <img id="infoIcon" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/5874228b-d8b5-4335-9d1b-5e623a35b987%2Finfo.png?1498790716495">
      </assets>
      <a-sky id="pano" radius="10" src="#reception"></a-sky>
      <a-camera wasd-control="false">
        <a-cursor id="cursor" geometry="primitive: circle; radius: 0.03" material="side: double" opacity="0.5" visible="true"></a-cursor>
        <a-entity id="textPopover" geometry="primitive: plane; width: 1.5; height: 0.6" material="color: black" text="value: Engage your viewers with the Showroom 360 Panorama tour. While exploring, viewers can be informed when hotspots were clicked. Hotspots may include the specifications and especially the features of the products through images, texts, video and many more.; width: 1.5; color: #fff" position="0 0 -1" visible="false">
        </a-entity>
      </a-camera>

      <!-- hotspot for text -->
      <a-image id="hotspotText" src="#infoIcon" position="-3 1.5 7" rotation="0 -20 0" visible="true"></a-image>

      <a-image id="sceneHotspot1" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/5874228b-d8b5-4335-9d1b-5e623a35b987%2Farrow.png?1498790627250" position="2 -1 4" rotation="90 30 0" opacity="1" visible="true">
        <a-mouseenter opacity="0.5"></a-mouseenter>
        <a-mouseleave opacity="1"></a-mouseleave>
      </a-image>
    </a-scene>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the three.js library when You use a-frame, as it consists of the core three.js library. Adding three.js AFTER a-frame could overwrite some core functions/definitions.
 
I've found out that the `text` attribute is not rendering properly, found out Your includes, threw out `three.js`, and now it is working as You intended it to.

Here is a live [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/v4ny81uo/).
I'm pretty sure, that Your plane+text are in front of the cursor, so You can't close it. Other than that, it seems to be working, still, You got multiple error logs connected to Your functions. [image: screen]

---

Moreover, when I go to the 2nd room and back, the arrow responsible for img changing is in the wrong position.

Comment: Thank you! I will do what you have said.